# Unable to run a Ruby application on Apache2

Tags: ruby

I try to run Snorby ; a Ruby application ; on an Apache server thanks to Passenger. I follow some guides on the Internet but I have a problematic issue.

httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin root@localhost
        ServerName snorby.linuxdrops.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/http/snorby/public
        ErrorLog logs/snorby-error_log
        CustomLog logs/snorby-access_log custom
        <Directory /srv/http/snorby/public>
                AllowOverride all
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And that is my error when I try to access on my Ruby application on port 80 from another computer :

```
[root@alarmpi logs]# tail -f error_log
[Wed Jul 03 17:12:26 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-07-03 17:12:46.4255 26353/b5a5f450 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 26384 stdout]
[ 2013-07-03 17:14:16.4516 26353/b5a5f450 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:774 ]: Could not spawn process for group /srv/http/snorby#default: An error occurred while starting up the preloader        : it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::Backgr        oundIOCapturerPtr&, const DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:150)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:558)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:707)

[ 2013-07-03 17:14:16.4535 26353/b58ff450 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1885 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did no        t write a startup response in time.
```

Do you have any idea ?